# rotation in jquery (or javascript), on page enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I found some code on stackoverflow to  extend jquery and do a rotation when an element is clicked on but I couldn't figure out how to make this work (animation-like) with a simple document.ready.... Here's what I have found so far (this is the "on-click" jquery plugin):

```
<div class="rotate">
    <h1>Rotatey text</h1>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript">

    var rotation = 0;

    jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
        $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
    };

    $('.rotate').click(function() {
        rotation += 5;
        $(this).rotate(rotation);
    });

</script>
```

So I changed some of it to make it rotate on page enter for my own code (this works but not in an "animation way - it just appears already rotated):

```
<style>
#pic1 {
    background: url(chpt3_pg1_WelcomeR10b.png) no-repeat top center; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-left:1px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

/* Rotate div */
-ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform:rotate(0deg); /* Standard syntax */

}
</style>

  <div id="pic1"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var rotation = 60;
jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};


$('#pic1').rotate(rotation);
</script>
```

The above rotated the pic 60 degress but, like I said, not in an animation so I tried putting it in the animate method within the css parameters and it doesn't work... I don't know if I am missing something or if it just can't be done in the css within the animate function:

```
<style>
    #pic1 {
        background: url(chpt3_pg1_WelcomeR10b.png) no-repeat top center; 
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-left:1px;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;

    /* Rotate div */
    -ms-transform:rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform:rotate(0deg); /* Standard syntax */

    }
</style>

<div id="pic1"> </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#pic1').animate({

           '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ 60 +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ 60 +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ 60 +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ 60 +'deg)'


    }, 1500);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jquery animate doesn't work for rotation, at least on that way.
Here's how we did animations on Javascript before the jquery era:

```
var rotation = 0;
var targetRotation = 60;


jQuery.fn.rotate = function(degrees) {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-moz-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 '-ms-transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)',
                 'transform' : 'rotate('+ degrees +'deg)'});
};

function Timer() {
    if (rotation < targetRotation) {
        rotation++;
        $('#pic1').rotate(rotation);
        setTimeout(Timer, 100); //Set in milliseconds
    }
}
Timer();
```

Try it out on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4JpEe/

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 transitions are used to handle transform animations: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp

I would set up a separate class with 60deg rotations and only apply this class to the .rotate element on page load. Set your CSS transition time to 1.5s and you should get the right result.

Comment: I will check into this more. Thanks you :)

Comment: http://www.cssrotate.com shows how this would work. This is the smoothest way to animate a rotation, given the user's browser supports CSS3.